# Help converting Cartesian to Spherical Symbolically

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I am attempting to use Mathematica for basic coordinate conversion symbolically but I am struggling to get it working. In the example below I am trying to convert from cartesian to spherical. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
A = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
(* Out: Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] *)
    
f[x_, y_, z_] = 
     TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
      A , {x, y, z} -> {r, θ, ϕ}]
```

returns the following error and the expression unchanged:

> TransformedField::nocoord: {x,y,x^2+y^2} is not a non-empty list of valid variables.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on MMA 12.3 on Win10-64. I obtain a reasonable result and no error. The result is `Sqrt[r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2)]`.

Comment: Try running your code in a fresh notebook.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
f[{r_, θ_, ϕ_}] = TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", A, {x, y, z} -> {r, θ, ϕ}](*Without PowerExpand and Simplify*)
(*Sqrt[r^2 Sin[θ]^2 (Cos[ϕ]^2 + Sin[ϕ]^2)]*)
```

Comment: That worked, the only issue is the output is wrong for some reason. The comment under my post has the correct answer to it.